# SwiftUI Button selection

Tags: swift, button, uibutton, swiftui, selected

I'm trying to grasp SwiftUI concepts (finished Apple's SwiftUI tutorials) but it seems hard for me after UIKit decade.

I need to switch state of multiple buttons in HStack by clicking on them (UIKit's `isSelected`), and change their font and text (in UIKit world i would use `attributedText` property in `if` statement examinig `isSelected` property, all in `@IBAction` on `TouchUpInside`).

My first thought was to get "reference" of Button in its action block, but it feels like it's not the SwiftUI way (and is not even possible). I found the solution that's using Configurator and its isPressed property (which is not what I searching for), but i need the Button to behave like toggle actually. Is there any built-in isSelected substitution in SwiftUI, or I have to make my own View implementation with @State or @BindableObject that will encapsulate some gesture recognizer (seems pretty ugly). Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're right (about a lot of things), including that SwiftUI is, when possible, *only* about UI. There is no "state of multiple buttons" - to be honest, "state" means something totally different, look up `@State`. Button "state" is actually built into the SwiftUI `Button`. Check these two out: https://alejandromp.com/blog/2019/06/09/playing-with-swiftui-buttons/  https://alejandromp.com/blog/2019/06/22/swiftui-reusable-button-style/

Comment: There isn't any problem with changing the font or text in a button's label, as long as the data comes from a observed variable so that SwiftUI detects the change. AFAIK the only thing that you can't do is use the press to make a change, I believe that actions are triggered by the release. Apple uses a button as a toggle for favourites in the Landmarks tutorial, it also change the appearance from an open star to a filled star. Any State can affect any View so you could extend the favourite star to 5 stars and use `fav >= 3` to affect the 3rd star's label and `fav = 3` in it's action.

Comment: Thanks for replies, pals. And sorry for inconvenience, I didn't mean "state of multiple buttons" as conjunction of every single button state reduced to "global state of buttons group", by this I meant isSelected state for every single button like in UIKit, that's it, I mentioned multiple buttons only to show that storing a state as @State in my View (isSelected=true/false) is not an option, cause I have many buttons, and state is individual for each (so it must be stored by every particular button itself).

Comment: @dfd I read the links you provided, thanks for that, but couldn't find anything related to "Button "state" is actually built into the SwiftUI Button". Could you please be more specific on that?

Comment: @MichaelSalmon thanks for the comment, the problem is that Apple's example uses model's isFavorite property to simply if-else button appearance in it's Label closure. The only thing I can come up with is create custom View that's encapsulating Button and count every touch up inside as 2x isPressed counter, or have just View with gesture recognizer. Seems odd for me that to accomplish something that costs 2 lines of code in UIKit you have to really wrap your head around how to do it :/

Comment: Take any Button - particularly those in the links I mentioned, but really just your run of the mill SwiftUI `Button`. Press or tap it, it already animates. That's pretty much what `touchUpInside` does. nI didn't mean "State as in `@State`, I meant "state as in `UIButtonState`.

Comment: If you don't like a lot of State variables the I would guess that you could use a set to contain the state of all buttons although I haven't tried it. If you are going to do something useful with your buttons though and not just change the colour every time that someone presses them then you need all those variables. As for creating custom views, if I have a few buttons that are similar then I make a custom view. Views are cheap, it's the stuff under the hood that costs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came up with the custom View, that's encapsulating Button like this:

```
    import SwiftUI

struct SelectableButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    var isSelected = false

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(width: 60.0, height: 60.0, alignment: .center)
            .padding()
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.8980392157, blue: 0.7058823529, alpha: 1)))
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: isSelected ? 16.0 : 0.0))
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: isSelected ? 16.0 : 0.0).stroke(lineWidth: isSelected ? 2.0 : 0.0).foregroundColor(Color.pink))
            .animation(.linear)
    }
}


struct StatedButton<Label>: View where Label: View {


    private let action: (() -> ())?

    private let label: (() -> Label)?

    @State var buttonStyle = SelectableButtonStyle()

    init(action: (() -> ())? = nil, label: (() -> Label)? = nil) {
        self.action = action
        self.label = label
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.buttonStyle.isSelected = !self.buttonStyle.isSelected
            self.action?()
            print("isSelected now is \(self.buttonStyle.isSelected ? "true" : "false")")
        }) {
            label?()
        }
        .buttonStyle(buttonStyle)
    }    
}
```

Please let me know if this solution is not good and why, I really appreciate it. And also I'm struggling with pretty trivial problem: how to map my model's array elements to buttons (i.e. how to detect what button exactly has been tapped), but I think I have to create another question for this.

Comment: Feels like a lot of work, but I suppose UIButton has so much functionality. To get it to work in a toolbar I  had to change the protocol conformance to PrimitiveButtonStyle.

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple way to do this.

```
    @State var selected = false

    func createButton() -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.selected.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Hello World")
                .padding(.all, 5)
                .background(selected ? Color.blue : Color.white)
                .foregroundColor(selected ? Color.white : Color.blue)
        })
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }
```

Comment: self.$selected.wrappedValue.toggle()

Comment: Could you please say how to use it to call this function

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom ButtonStyle and modify the configuration's label based on `isPressed`

```
struct CustomButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // action
        } label: {
            Text("Button")
        }
        .buttonStyle(CustomStyle())
    }
}

struct CustomStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? .green : .black)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the implementation by `ButtonStyle` with custom `Environment` "isSelected". The following codes have some custom values for colours & etc. but I hope you will catch the idea ;-)

```
extension ButtonStyle where Self == ButtonStyleGrey {
    internal static var grey: ButtonStyleGrey {
        ButtonStyleGrey()
    }
}

struct ButtonStyleGrey: ButtonStyle {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) private var isEnabled: Bool
    @Environment(\.isSelected) private var isSelected: Bool

    func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        let font = Font.system(size: UIScreen.titleFontSize, weight: .semibold)
        let text: UIColor = isEnabled ? .titleColor : .systemGray2
        let back: UIColor = isEnabled ? (configuration.isPressed || isSelected ? .graySelected : .grayNormal) : .disabledColor
        
        return configuration
            .label
            .textCase(.uppercase)
            .font(font)
            .foregroundColor(Color(text))
            .padding(.regular)
            .background(Color(back))
    }
}

// MARK: -

private struct isSelectedKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = false
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var isSelected: Bool {
        get { self[isSelectedKey.self] }
        set { self[isSelectedKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

extension View {
    func isSelected(_ selected: Bool) -> some View {
        environment(\.isSelected, selected)
    }
}
```

The usage is just like that:

```
   Button("Some action") {
       // run something
   }
   .buttonStyle(.grey)
   .isSelected(viewModel.someActionSelected)
```